# How to add additional functionality into existing apk file

Tags: java, android

I have an apk file but i have to add some additional functionalities to the existing apk file. Is this possible?

Comment: No. You need to get source code, edit it and rebuild it.

Comment: is there previos apk are build by you?

Comment: if yes then you can do. if no then it is impossible to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have develop project and generate apk then you can update with same package. or if you have sign certificate which generated at creation time so you can do it.